# Defining Functions in Object.create()

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I want to create an object just using the `Object.create` function (without any prototype, *first argument as null*).

I read somewhere that properties determine the state of an object in JavaScript and JavaScript has three different kinds of properties:

- named data properties
- named accessor properties
- internal properties

So when I define a function in an object, should I always define it as a `named accessor property`:

```
var obj = Object.create(null, {   
     a:{
        get:function(){
           alert('jQuery nyan!');          
        }
     }
});​
```

Or should I just define the function as a `named data property` when it is neither a `setter` nor a `getter`? [e.g some jQuery functions that makes changes to the DOM obj]

```
var obj = Object.create(null, {
     a:{
        value:function(){
              alert('jQuery nyan!');          
        }
     }
});​
```

Which approach should I take? In terms of performance (speed) and memory management do they have differences? They both appear to work without any exception.

```
obj.a;
//output: 'jQuery nyan!'
```

Comment: Please also remove the illegal zero-width character tokens from the end of your code blocks (I can't edit them because it'd be just -2 chars; not a big enough diff)

Comment: With `obj.a` as a getter, `obj.a()` invokes the method and then throws and error `TypeError: Property 'a' of object object is not a function` because the getter's method does not return a function for the `()` to invoke. (To invoke the method you just need to do `obj.a`)

Comment: @PaulS. Ooh yeah. I received the same error in my console too but it's weird that my browser still executes the function. Thanks for pointing that out! After removing the zero width character token, it invokes the method properly and the `TypeError` is no longer being triggered. I'm wrong to have thought that `obj.a` is exactly the same as `obj.a()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it easier to refer to them, let's define them as follows

```
var objA = Object.create(null, {a: {get:  function(){alert('jQuery nyan!');}}});
var objB = Object.create(null, {a: {value:function(){alert('jQuery nyan!');}}});
```

Now, there is almost no difference between the invocation of `objA.a` vs `objB.a()`, except the use of `()`.

There are some differences, however.
The main difference is that you can't pass parameters to a getter, it is invoked as-is. This means `objA.a(1,2,3)` will not invoke the function with arugments `1, 2, 3`. It will in fact throw an error *after* invoking, assuming the getter does not return a *Function* (you're effectively trying to do `undefined(1,2,3)`).

A second difference requires us to remember [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)'s second parameter takes an object of [descriptors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description), which includes the flag `writable` (which defaults to *false*). The difference here is you can not set `writable:true` on `objA.a` because "A property cannot both have accessors and be writable or have a value". This means that if you want the method of the getter changed, you must re-define the property, whereas for *value* you could enable the use of `=` to change the method associated with the property.

Additionally, with no setter `objA.a = <expr>` will not perform any action at all.

Normally, you'd only use getters and setters in the following instances, with `value` as the standard behaviour otherwise;

- Lightweight calculating an output
- Validating input (to protect an object)
- Hiding a variable from direct access
- Keeping a standard API where variable or property names may change

Comment: Thanks! I've once again gained a deeper understanding of Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about compatibility, using `getter` and `setters` could be a good approach to replace `setNAME()`s and `getNAME()`s. And there is [no significant performance gain/loss comparing to function version](http://jsperf.com/direct-property-access-vs-getter-function/2).

Note that, cause it looks like accessing an variable, instead of calling a function, so the `getter/setter` function should be very light weight to meet this expectation.

And don't ever use *one* function for both getter and setter like jQuery does, it's simply very slow. As there is no function signature in javascript, simulate it with `if/else` will cause lots of performance loss.

Comment: @Arch if you want to be GOOD at javascript, don't start with jQuery. It's basically a library telling you what you should never do.

Comment: I die a little on the inside every time I see people relying on jQuery for something every post-IE6 browser is able to do naively.

Comment: hahas sure! I shall stick using `document.getElementById()` instead of `$()` syntax.

Comment: @PaulS. exactly, really painful. I ignored all jquery related tags.